# read parameters from txt

Tags: python, text

I have a txt file containing some parameters. The txt file looks like this:

```
par1 = 10.81
par2 = 0.3
par3 = 0.5
```

I would like to read it in python and create automatically all the variables specified in the txt.

What is the best file to read a configuration file and create the parameters listed there?

in particular say that I have a class
how can I have the following?

```
class MyClass:
  def __init__(self)
     self.par1 = par1
     self.par2 = par2
     self.par3 = par3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**DANGEROUS CODE AHEAD**

You could use [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#exec). 
Consider the file `foo.txt`:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
```

and the code:

```
with open('foo.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        exec(line)
print(a)
# 1
print(b)
# 2
print(c)
# 3
```

**BUT**, as the header says, this is a dangerous approach as `foo.txt` can be easily modified to contain

```
import os
os.remove('C:\system\a_very_important_system_file')
```

and `exec` will happily execute it.

**THE SAFE APPROACH**

Change `foo.txt` to JSON format:

```
{"a": 1,
 "b": 2,
 "c": 3}
```

And use the `json` module to load it in your code:

```
import json

with open('foo.txt') as f:
    variables = json.load(f)

print(variables["a"])
# 1
```

**EDIT**

If you need to dynamically initiate instance attributes from an unknown JSON file you can use [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
import json

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        with open('foo.txt') as f:
            variables = json.load(f)
        for key, value in variables.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)
```

Comment: Thank you. What is then the best way to load some configuration parameters in my script? These are parameters of a class..

Comment: @gabboshow I've added the correct and safe way to do it using `json`.

Comment: I have edited my question... is it possible to do it in the constructor of a class?

Comment: @gabboshow Yes, you can read files inside the `__init__` method.

Comment: how do I assign them to self?

Comment: This implies that I should already know what is in the foo.txt... I would like to have all the parameters in foo.txt available in my class without modifying the __init__ if a new parameter is added... sorry for not being totally clear before

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer provided by @DeepSpace, you could **restrict** the allowed values with a regular expression:

```
import re

string = """
par1 = 10.81
par2 = 0.3
par3 = 0.5 
"""

rx = re.compile(r'^(?P<key>\w+)\s*=\s*(?P<value>[\d.]+)', re.MULTILINE)

for var in rx.finditer(string):
    exec("{} = {}".format(var.group('key'), var.group('value')))

print(par1)
# 10.81
```

Here, only numerical values are allowed for the values (`0-9.`) and `a-z_` for the variable names. Adjust as needed (ie to allow strings as well).

---

An alternative would be to use a container for the parameters, ie a dict:

```
params = {match.group('key'): match.group('value')
            for match in rx.finditer(string)}
print(params)
# {'par1': '10.81', 'par2': '0.3', 'par3': '0.5'}
```

You would then call your variables via `params['par1']`.

Answer (score -1):

After you read the file with readlines()

```
with open("sample.txt") as f:
    fr = f.readlines()

    fr = ['par1 = 10.81\n', 'par2 = 0.3\n', 'par3 = 0.5\n', 'par4 = 0.7\n', 'par5 = 0.9\n'] # Output

    fr = [f[:-1] for f in fr]

    frs = [f.split(" = ") for f in fr]

    for i, j in frs:
        exec("%s = %s" % (i,j))
```

Comment: The use of `exec` is unsafe and should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: yea you are right http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/2/1/exec-in-python/, this explains it .

Answer (score -2):

You are looking for the eval function.

`with open('foo.txt','r') as fil:
  for line in fil:
    eval(line)`

Comment: There is almost not a good enough reason to use `eval` or `exec`, including this use case.

Comment: missed a line there, maybe now this will work @gabboshow

Comment: Agreed - please refer to @DeepSpace 's answer